# Types of Mat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, types

I have the following:

```
Mat bladArray(Mat base) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int x = 0; x < base.cols; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < base.rows; y++) {
            vec.push_back(y * base.cols + x);
        }
    }
    return Mat(vec);
}

//input =   VideoCapture cap(0);
//fish is similair to bladArray

 Mat warp(Mat input) {
    if (!f) {
        fish = genfish(input);
        f = true;
    }
    if (!b) {
        base = bladArray(input);
        b = true;
    }

    Mat ret;
    remap(input, ret, base, fish,  0, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
    return ret;
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3128: error: (-215) ((map1.type() == CV_32FC2 || map1.type() == CV_16SC2) && !map2.data) || (map1.type() == CV_32FC1 && map2.type() == CV_32FC1) in function remap
```

I understand that this means that the types are incorrect but how do types in opencv work?

Is there an easy way to set the types of a mat to one that is accepted by remap? What types are accepted by remap anyway?

Comment: Checkout the Doc [page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap), also see an example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html)

Comment: you are making the bladArray from a std::vector<int>, so the resulting Mat will be CV_32S. if you use a std::vector<float>, it will be the desired CV_32F. also see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap), please

Comment: You are right so a float becomes a CV32_F and a int will be a CV_32S so the F denotes a float the s a int and the 32 the number of bits? And what are the rules of remap anyway (still can't quite follow that one).